# Отправка формы Ajax Yii2.0

Tags: php, ajax, yii, yii2

Здравствуйте. Нужно отправить данные формы ajax-ом. 
Во вьюхе подгружен виджет коментов
Вьюха

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="reviews">
<?=\frontend\widgets\CommentWidget::widget(array('from'=>$result['id'])); ?>
</div>
```

Контролер виджета

```
namespace frontend\widgets;

use app\models\Comment;

use common\models\User;
use yii\bootstrap\Widget;
use yii\db\Query;

class CommentWidget extends Widget
{

    private $name;
    public $from;
    public $params = array();

    public function init() {
        $user = new User();
        $this->name = $user->getUserName();
    }

    public function run() {
        $model = new Comment();
        $temp = new Query();
        $list = $temp->from('comment')->where(['from'=>$this->from])->all();

        return $this->render('CreateForm', ['model' => $model,
        'list' => $list], $this->from);
    }
}
```

Вьюха виджета:

```
<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'create_comment',
    'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/cafe/view'),
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validateOnBlur' => true,
    'validateOnChange' => true,
    //'validationUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('cafe/view')
]);
?>

<?=$form->field($model, 'text')->textarea(); ?>
<?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::submitButton('Опубликовать'); ?>

    <?php if(empty($list)) : ?>

        <h3>Коментариев нет</h3>

    <?php else : ?>
       <?php foreach ($list as $value) : ?>
           <div class="result">
               <p><?=$value['entity']?></p>
               <p>Текст сообщения: <?=$value['text']?></p>
           </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#create_comment').on('beforeSubmit\',function(event, jrXHR, settings)
{
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cafe/view",

        type: "get",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
        alert("fsdgdfgdf");
    },
    error: function(data){
        $('.result').html("Error");
        }
    });
    );
</script>
```

как сделать что бы данные отправлялись через ajax?

Comment: Кто-то знает ка решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$("#create_comment").submit( function(event)
{
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : action,
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    event.unbind();
});
```

Для вызова Widget'a из контроллера я делаю следующее:

```
class CafeController extends yii\web\Controller 
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'get-comment-widget' => CommentWidgetAction::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

И *Action*:

```
class CommentWidgetAction extends yii\base\Action
{
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->controller->renderContent(DeleteDomain::widget());
    }
}
```

Comment: а как правильно написать путь на контролер виджета?

Comment: @MykolaShkit В смысле как вызывать метод виджета?

Comment: просто в action я могу только написать путь к контолеру/акшену, а не к виджету

Comment: То есть выходите, чтобы ajax запрос возвращал виджет?

Comment: да. у меня во вьюхе загружается виджет с формой и списком уже коментариев. нужно с формы виджета пережать в контолер виджета

Comment: @MykolaShkit Отредактировал свой ответ. Может быть вам это поможет